# testing the hypothesis that a set of data comes from a particular distribution D

Tags: statistics

I have a distribution D described by a function f(x) with all the nessisary properties of a pmf, I also have n data points which under my null hypothesis come from this distribution, I would like to calculate a p-value for the probability that this data came from this distribution.

It is not as simple as finding a p-value for each data point and combining them is some way because for example if the distribution were a standard normal distribution and all the data points were 0 this would result in a low p-value however the probability that all the data should be that close to the mean is small.

One solution I have considered is to look at the mean of the data and the variance of the data and compare this to a normal distribution however there are many distributions with the same mean and variance.

I hope this problem is clear, please ask any clarifying questions in the comments and I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To characterize the goodness of fit of a particular distribution for your raw data, it is customary to use the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test). This test quantifies the goodness of fit using the *K-S statistic* $D_n$ defined as
$$
D_n = \sup\limits_{x} |F_n(x) - F(x)|.
$$
Here $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of the theoretical distribution, and $F_n(x)$ is the empirical distribution function of the raw data sample. There is a lot of literature helping interpret the K-S statistic values. (See e.g. the literature cited in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test).)
A variant of the K-S test can also help you check whether two samples of raw data come from the same distribution.

In practice, one of the easiest ways might be to use distribution-fitting software such as [EasyFit](http://www.mathwave.com/easyfit-distribution-fitting.html). The software will help you not only calculate the goodness-of-fit statistic for your raw data using various distributions, but also interpret your goodness-of-fit results.

Comment: could you elaborate on why the KS test won't give you a p-value? One sample (appropriate for testing data against a distribution ) KS tests in R happily return p-values.

Comment: @PM You are right! Removed the misleading note.